# How to edit a UITableViewCell in a completion block from a method called inside the delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the UITableView delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, I want to set the image for a cell imageView. If the image is not available, i would like to download it and then set it asynchronously in the complete block. The problem is that because the cells are reusable, maybe when the completion block is called, the cell may not exist anymore.
How can I update the cell when the completion block is called? or is this way ok?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FriendTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Friend Cell"];

    Friend *friend = self.friends[indexPath.row];

    if (friend.picture) {
        cell.userProfileImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:pictureData];
    } else {
        cell.userProfileImageView.image = nil;

        NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal&return_ssl_res", friend.facebookId]];

        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pictureURL];

        // Run network request asynchronously
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
             if (connectionError == nil && data != nil) {
                 friend.picture = data;
                 FriendTableViewCell *cellToUpdate = (FriendTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                 cellToUpdate.userProfileImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
             }
         }];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your completion handler simply ask the table to reload the affected row. As your data model now has the picture, it will update correctly. This also protects you against cells being off screen which will result in a noop(). When you scroll back all will be well as the picture is now in your data model.

So something like:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
             if (connectionError == nil && data != nil) {
                 friend.picture = data;
                 self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]
             }
         }];
```

If you decide to run the asynchronous request in a non main thread, you need to schedule the row reload on the main thread.